# Azure SQL trial balance previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table with data. The opening balances are pre calculated for each year, there is always a figure for January. I want the opening balances to carry over for each month, including any net change amount. Therefore the opening balance fields (accounting/transaction) would be defined as cumulative `AccountingOpeningBalance` from start of year up until end of previous month + `AccountingNetChangeAmount`). I will also post screenshot of what I'm trying to do. What's the best way of doing this in SQL? This is a full load of all data for another system, so won't be entering start/end dates.

*** ON HOLD DOING FURTHER INVESTIGATION ***

[image]

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST]    Script Date: 29/12/2021 17:04:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST](
    [Company] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MainAccount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PortFolioProject] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionCurrency] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [AccountingOpeningBalance] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [AccountingNetChangeAmount] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [TransactionOpeningBalance] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [TransactionNetChangeAmount] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL,
    [Period] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'AUD', CAST(-141194.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-205000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'BMD', CAST(-27255.140000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-27255.140000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CAD', CAST(-2428.080000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-3220.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(-220514.900000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-210500.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(-1213310.030000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-1084078.320000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(-2449684.590000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-1895760.520000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(8235414.760000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(8235414.760000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(-3162799.570000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-3162799.570000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20701, N'USD', CAST(-8538.750000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-8538.750000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20706, N'CAD', CAST(-9189.700000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-12000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'AUD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-17038.670000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-22378.080000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'AUD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-115.330000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-148.800000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 5, N'MAY', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'AUD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-16453.140000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-21946.300000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'AUD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-72603.980000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-100100.880000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'BMD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-39.500000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-39.500000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 5, N'MAY', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CAD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-16671.250000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-20634.560000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CAD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-27757.730000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-33660.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CAD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-13185.850000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-16632.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-13370.400000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-12000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 2, N'FEB', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-5417.500000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-5000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-84489.200000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-76000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-10898.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-10000.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'CHF', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-34316.100000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-31500.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-60065.090000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-49407.820000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-60479.040000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-49863.170000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 2, N'FEB', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-12680.530000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-10630.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 3, N'MAR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-147617.210000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-124488.790000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-60692.420000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-49850.040000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 5, N'MAY', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-72969.800000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-59846.750000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-67855.430000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-57475.380000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'EUR', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-89161.800000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-75624.430000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-358602.930000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-263658.790000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-342658.990000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-246690.900000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 2, N'FEB', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-24548.700000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-17629.940000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 3, N'MAR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-22602.180000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-16337.060000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-408572.870000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-289051.220000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 5, N'MAY', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-81834.950000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-58166.600000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-656762.450000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-476738.700000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'GBP', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-184405.370000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-134115.420000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(426074.270000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(426074.270000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(466995.850000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(466995.850000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 2, N'FEB', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(42436.370000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(42436.370000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 3, N'MAR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(211274.660000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(211274.660000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(467332.520000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(467332.520000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 5, N'MAY', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(324603.360000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(324603.360000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(908661.630000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(908661.630000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 696, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(523337.300000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(523337.300000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-7406.250000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-7406.250000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 1, N'JAN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-50487.420000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-50487.420000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 2, N'FEB', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-4525.400000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-4525.400000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 3, N'MAR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-1927.850000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-1927.850000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 4, N'APR', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-55464.080000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-55464.080000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 6, N'JUN', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-143506.760000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-143506.760000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 7, N'JUL', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20698, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-142850.050000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-142850.050000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 8, N'AUG', 2021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST] ([Company], [MainAccount], [PortFolioProject], [TransactionCurrency], [AccountingOpeningBalance], [AccountingNetChangeAmount], [TransactionOpeningBalance], [TransactionNetChangeAmount], [Month], [Period], [Year]) VALUES (1234, 123456, 20701, N'USD', CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-681.740000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), CAST(-681.740000 AS Numeric(38, 6)), 3, N'MAR', 2021)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST ORDER BY Month
```

Comment: `sum(AccountingOpeningBalance+case month when 1 then 0 else AccountingNetChangeAmount end) over(partition by company, mainaccount, portfolioproject, transactioncurrency, year order by month) …`

Comment: I tried to use LAG, but with the varying currencies couldn't quite get the results/partition I wanted... @Iptr will try your suggestion thanks.

Comment: @Iptr this is incorrect the accountopeningbalance for jan-apr at least should be the same for each month 1000500 as the net change is 0 for these months. That figure of 1000500 should be carrying through each month.

Comment: in the example data, all months(except jan) have AccountingNetChangeAmount <> 0.. and there is no opening balance of 1000500

Comment: If there is an AccountingOpeningBalance <> 0 for a month other than Jan, then exclude all balances and sum only the Jan one  `sum(case month when 1 then AccountingOpeningBalance else 0 end + case month when 1 then 0 else AccountingNetChangeAmount end)...`

Comment: so figures for Jan match, however the accountopeningbalance is not carrying over it needs to be cumulative, as shown in my screenshot. The net change amount needs to be from the previous month as shown in my screenshot, annoyingly stack overflow limited my ability to insert data 30000 char limit, what is the best way of posting dml/ddl SQL fiddle or something? I will be able to post more data... the screenshot pretty much exactly describes what i'm trying to do... I will be adding a big bounty to this question i know it's complicated.

Comment: edit the question and add the expected result for one currency, for eg. `select *
from [dbo].[RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST]
where transactioncurrency = 'aud'` , for the AUD rows, what should be the calculated “ AccountingOpeningBalance from start of year up until end of previous month + AccountingNetChangeAmount” ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240573/discussion-between-jhowe-and-lptr).

Comment: Added to chat so frustrating with the character limits...

Comment: Any clarifying detail should be added to/in the question, not found only in some chat history.  You said you tried.  Where is your attempted SQL in the question, along with the result and why you don't like the result?  Explain clearly and logically, what is missing in your SQL logic that you aren't able to include?  A running monthly sum per year doesn't seem difficult.  A window function can do that.

Comment: In Jan, in some cases, you have an _opening value_ and a _net change_ for the same apparent group/partition, with no obvious way to order the rows/calculation in the result.  What is your requirement here?  Show the exact expected result, given your test data.

Comment: Is the current _net change_ included in the current balance for any row?  If so, do you want to ignore the _net change_ for January rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, where we allow for both an *Opening Balance* and a *Net Change* in the same month (usually that occurs in January).

Note: I've included the AccountOpen and Account Net Change in the current month's AccountBalance (ABal), and this is accumulated for each subsequent month in each year, starting over with the next year.

The same applies to the TransactionOpen and Transaction Net Change, etc.

But let's adjust the logic to apply the Net Change rows after any Opening Balance rows to start each year.

Later, we can (if required) fill in any missing monthly data with the last available month's calculation in this year, as needed.

```sql
SELECT Year, Month AS Mon, Period, MainAccount AS Acct, PortFolioProject AS Folio, Company AS Comp, TransactionCurrency AS TCur
     , AccountingOpeningBalance   AS AOpen
     , AccountingNetChangeAmount  AS ANet
     , SUM(AccountingOpeningBalance  + AccountingNetChangeAmount)  OVER (PARTITION BY Year, MainAccount, PortFolioProject, Company, TransactionCurrency ORDER BY Month, AccountingNetChangeAmount DESC) AS ABal
     , TransactionOpeningBalance  AS TOpen
     , TransactionNetChangeAmount AS TNet
     , SUM(TransactionOpeningBalance + TransactionNetChangeAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, MainAccount, PortFolioProject, Company, TransactionCurrency ORDER BY Month, TransactionNetChangeAmount DESC) AS TBal
  FROM RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST
 WHERE TransactionCurrency = 'EUR'
 ORDER BY Company, MainAccount, PortFolioProject, TransactionCurrency, Year, Month, AccountingOpeningBalance
;
```

The following result is based on the given data in the question, plus some duplicated rows copied with 2022 dates, to show how the calculation restarts for each year.

Also the result is based on adding the following filter to the query, to show just the 'EUR' related results, to simplify the review.

`WHERE TransactionCurrency = 'EUR'`

Notice also that I didn't group the common (Open/Net Change) rows within the same month, but that's easily done.  I simply summed them together with a window function.  This is only seen in January, in the current data, where the Open and Net Change are both non-0.

```
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Year | Mon  | Period | Acct   | Folio | Comp | TCur | AOpen        | ANet        | ABal         | TOpen        | TNet        | TBal         |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  | -1213310.030 |       0.000 | -1213310.030 | -1084078.320 |       0.000 | -1084078.320 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60065.090 | -1273375.120 |        0.000 |  -49407.820 | -1133486.140 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60479.040 | -1333854.160 |        0.000 |  -49863.170 | -1183349.310 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -12680.530 | -1346534.690 |        0.000 |  -10630.000 | -1193979.310 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 | -147617.210 | -1494151.900 |        0.000 | -124488.790 | -1318468.100 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60692.420 | -1554844.320 |        0.000 |  -49850.040 | -1368318.140 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -72969.800 | -1627814.120 |        0.000 |  -59846.750 | -1428164.890 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -67855.430 | -1695669.550 |        0.000 |  -57475.380 | -1485640.270 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -89161.800 | -1784831.350 |        0.000 |  -75624.430 | -1561264.700 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  | -1213310.030 |       0.000 | -1213310.030 | -1084078.320 |       0.000 | -1084078.320 |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

The full result looks something like this:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Year | Mon  | Period | Acct   | Folio | Comp | TCur | AOpen        | ANet        | ABal         | TOpen        | TNet        | TBal         |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |  -141194.000 |       0.000 |  -141194.000 |  -205000.000 |       0.000 |  -205000.000 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |  -17038.670 |  -158232.670 |        0.000 |  -22378.080 |  -227378.080 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |    -115.330 |  -158348.000 |        0.000 |    -148.800 |  -227526.880 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |  -16453.140 |  -174801.140 |        0.000 |  -21946.300 |  -249473.180 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |  -72603.980 |  -247405.120 |        0.000 | -100100.880 |  -349574.060 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |  -141194.000 |       0.000 |  -141194.000 |  -205000.000 |       0.000 |  -205000.000 |
| 2022 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |  -17038.670 |  -158232.670 |        0.000 |  -22378.080 |  -227378.080 |
| 2022 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |    -115.330 |  -158348.000 |        0.000 |    -148.800 |  -227526.880 |
| 2022 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | AUD  |        0.000 |  -16453.140 |  -174801.140 |        0.000 |  -21946.300 |  -249473.180 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | BMD  |   -27255.140 |       0.000 |   -27255.140 |   -27255.140 |       0.000 |   -27255.140 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | BMD  |        0.000 |     -39.500 |   -27294.640 |        0.000 |     -39.500 |   -27294.640 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | BMD  |   -27255.140 |       0.000 |   -27255.140 |   -27255.140 |       0.000 |   -27255.140 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CAD  |    -2428.080 |       0.000 |    -2428.080 |    -3220.000 |       0.000 |    -3220.000 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CAD  |        0.000 |  -16671.250 |   -19099.330 |        0.000 |  -20634.560 |   -23854.560 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CAD  |        0.000 |  -27757.730 |   -46857.060 |        0.000 |  -33660.000 |   -57514.560 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CAD  |        0.000 |  -13185.850 |   -60042.910 |        0.000 |  -16632.000 |   -74146.560 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CAD  |    -2428.080 |       0.000 |    -2428.080 |    -3220.000 |       0.000 |    -3220.000 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |  -220514.900 |       0.000 |  -220514.900 |  -210500.000 |       0.000 |  -210500.000 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |        0.000 |  -13370.400 |  -233885.300 |        0.000 |  -12000.000 |  -222500.000 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |        0.000 |   -5417.500 |  -239302.800 |        0.000 |   -5000.000 |  -227500.000 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |        0.000 |  -84489.200 |  -323792.000 |        0.000 |  -76000.000 |  -303500.000 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |        0.000 |  -10898.000 |  -334690.000 |        0.000 |  -10000.000 |  -313500.000 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |        0.000 |  -34316.100 |  -369006.100 |        0.000 |  -31500.000 |  -345000.000 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | CHF  |  -220514.900 |       0.000 |  -220514.900 |  -210500.000 |       0.000 |  -210500.000 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  | -1213310.030 |       0.000 | -1213310.030 | -1084078.320 |       0.000 | -1084078.320 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60065.090 | -1273375.120 |        0.000 |  -49407.820 | -1133486.140 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60479.040 | -1333854.160 |        0.000 |  -49863.170 | -1183349.310 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -12680.530 | -1346534.690 |        0.000 |  -10630.000 | -1193979.310 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 | -147617.210 | -1494151.900 |        0.000 | -124488.790 | -1318468.100 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -60692.420 | -1554844.320 |        0.000 |  -49850.040 | -1368318.140 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -72969.800 | -1627814.120 |        0.000 |  -59846.750 | -1428164.890 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -67855.430 | -1695669.550 |        0.000 |  -57475.380 | -1485640.270 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  |        0.000 |  -89161.800 | -1784831.350 |        0.000 |  -75624.430 | -1561264.700 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | EUR  | -1213310.030 |       0.000 | -1213310.030 | -1084078.320 |       0.000 | -1084078.320 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  | -2449684.590 |       0.000 | -2449684.590 | -1895760.520 |       0.000 | -1895760.520 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 | -358602.930 | -2808287.520 |        0.000 | -263658.790 | -2159419.310 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 | -342658.990 | -3150946.510 |        0.000 | -246690.900 | -2406110.210 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 |  -24548.700 | -3175495.210 |        0.000 |  -17629.940 | -2423740.150 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 |  -22602.180 | -3198097.390 |        0.000 |  -16337.060 | -2440077.210 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 | -408572.870 | -3606670.260 |        0.000 | -289051.220 | -2729128.430 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 |  -81834.950 | -3688505.210 |        0.000 |  -58166.600 | -2787295.030 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 | -656762.450 | -4345267.660 |        0.000 | -476738.700 | -3264033.730 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  |        0.000 | -184405.370 | -4529673.030 |        0.000 | -134115.420 | -3398149.150 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | GBP  | -2449684.590 |       0.000 | -2449684.590 | -1895760.520 |       0.000 | -1895760.520 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  426074.270 |   426074.270 |        0.000 |  426074.270 |   426074.270 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |  8235414.760 |       0.000 |  8661489.030 |  8235414.760 |       0.000 |  8661489.030 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  466995.850 |  9128484.880 |        0.000 |  466995.850 |  9128484.880 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |   42436.370 |  9170921.250 |        0.000 |   42436.370 |  9170921.250 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  211274.660 |  9382195.910 |        0.000 |  211274.660 |  9382195.910 |
| 2021 |    5 | MAY    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  467332.520 |  9849528.430 |        0.000 |  467332.520 |  9849528.430 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  324603.360 | 10174131.790 |        0.000 |  324603.360 | 10174131.790 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  908661.630 | 11082793.420 |        0.000 |  908661.630 | 11082793.420 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  523337.300 | 11606130.720 |        0.000 |  523337.300 | 11606130.720 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 |   696 | 1234 | USD  |  8235414.760 |       0.000 |  8235414.760 |  8235414.760 |       0.000 |  8235414.760 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  | -3162799.570 |       0.000 | -3162799.570 | -3162799.570 |       0.000 | -3162799.570 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |   -7406.250 | -3170205.820 |        0.000 |   -7406.250 | -3170205.820 |
| 2021 |    2 | FEB    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  -50487.420 | -3220693.240 |        0.000 |  -50487.420 | -3220693.240 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |   -4525.400 | -3225218.640 |        0.000 |   -4525.400 | -3225218.640 |
| 2021 |    4 | APR    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |   -1927.850 | -3227146.490 |        0.000 |   -1927.850 | -3227146.490 |
| 2021 |    6 | JUN    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |  -55464.080 | -3282610.570 |        0.000 |  -55464.080 | -3282610.570 |
| 2021 |    7 | JUL    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 | -143506.760 | -3426117.330 |        0.000 | -143506.760 | -3426117.330 |
| 2021 |    8 | AUG    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 | -142850.050 | -3568967.380 |        0.000 | -142850.050 | -3568967.380 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20698 | 1234 | USD  | -3162799.570 |       0.000 | -3162799.570 | -3162799.570 |       0.000 | -3162799.570 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20701 | 1234 | USD  |    -8538.750 |       0.000 |    -8538.750 |    -8538.750 |       0.000 |    -8538.750 |
| 2021 |    3 | MAR    | 123456 | 20701 | 1234 | USD  |        0.000 |    -681.740 |    -9220.490 |        0.000 |    -681.740 |    -9220.490 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20701 | 1234 | USD  |    -8538.750 |       0.000 |    -8538.750 |    -8538.750 |       0.000 |    -8538.750 |
| 2021 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20706 | 1234 | CAD  |    -9189.700 |       0.000 |    -9189.700 |   -12000.000 |       0.000 |   -12000.000 |
| 2022 |    1 | JAN    | 123456 | 20706 | 1234 | CAD  |    -9189.700 |       0.000 |    -9189.700 |   -12000.000 |       0.000 |   -12000.000 |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+------+------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You have essentially come to the same conclusion as me which is a combination of window functions and CASE statements within my SUMS to determine whether it is an opening or operating balance (fiscalperiodtype 0, 1 (opening, operating)). In hindsight I should have included this in the question but wasn't important to the user/end result. Your earlier comment was very helpful and made me realise I had an error in my data. There should not be any duplicate rows. I should be ok now I have pushed the business to give me a proper specification. If I have any issues will post another question. Thx!

Comment: Your earlier comment also made me realise that when I was trying to use window functions earlier, I needed to include FiscalPeriodType my partitions were incorrect, apologies I will make my question as concise as possible next time with my results/expected results. I'm a bit out of practise, this is the first question i've posted in a long time...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood you correctly.  If so, this is my attempt ...

```
SELECT *, 
    [AccountingCumulativeOpeningBalance]  = (
        CASE [Month]
            WHEN 1 THEN 0
            ELSE 
            ( 
                ( SELECT SUM(AccountingNetChangeAmount)
                    FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST AS I
                    WHERE I.Company = O.Company
                        AND I.MainAccount = O.MainAccount
                        AND I.PortFolioProject = O.PortFolioProject
                        AND I.TransactionCurrency = O.TransactionCurrency
                        AND I.Year = O.Year
                        AND I.Month < O.Month ) + 
                ( SELECT SUM(AccountingOpeningBalance)
                    FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST AS I
                    WHERE I.Company = O.Company
                        AND I.MainAccount = O.MainAccount
                        AND I.PortFolioProject = O.PortFolioProject
                        AND I.TransactionCurrency = O.TransactionCurrency
                        AND I.Year = O.Year
                        AND I.Month = 1 )
                )
        END ),
    [TransactionCumulativeOpeningBalance]  = (
        CASE [Month]
            WHEN 1 THEN 0
            ELSE 
            ( 
                ( SELECT SUM(TransactionNetChangeAmount)
                    FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST AS I
                    WHERE I.Company = O.Company
                        AND I.MainAccount = O.MainAccount
                        AND I.PortFolioProject = O.PortFolioProject
                        AND I.TransactionCurrency = O.TransactionCurrency
                        AND I.Year = O.Year
                        AND I.Month < O.Month ) + 
                ( SELECT SUM(TransactionOpeningBalance)
                    FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST AS I
                    WHERE I.Company = O.Company
                        AND I.MainAccount = O.MainAccount
                        AND I.PortFolioProject = O.PortFolioProject
                        AND I.TransactionCurrency = O.TransactionCurrency
                        AND I.Year = O.Year
                        AND I.Month = 1 )
                )
        END )
FROM dbo.RetrieveTrialBalanceTEST AS O
ORDER BY Company, MainAccount, PortFolioProject, TransactionCurrency, Month
```

Is it wordy?  **Yes**!  Could it be done better?  **Probably**!

I've reconciled the output and it correctly flows the balances forward month on month by each attribute grouping.  I saw no point in aggregating currencies and it made sense to aggregate on each attribute.

Also, personally, I'd store that data in another field.  Adding the data back to the original field, for me, is not required and muddies the water on what is from the source and what is calculated.

You could just build a view on top of your table which is essentially what my answer does.

I hope that's what you're after anyway.

Comment: Apologies i've noticed there's some issues with the base data and query i'm using, i'm going to fully re edit this when i'm absolutely clear on what needs to be done... wish there was some way i could freeze/put on hold the question...

Comment: What is the status @jhowe? Do you still need help or is this question is `on hold` ?

Comment: I want to put this on hold effectively for now, annoyingly I can't see a way of doing this on stack overflow. I'm doing some investigation on my side.