# How to get opening balance for each month

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

this is a continuation of [Azure SQL trial balance previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522642/azure-sql-trial-balance-previous-month). My query is essentially complete now, however i'm struggling to figure out how to add in missing months/periods. When there is an openingbalance (fiscalperiodtype 0) for an account, this should appear in results every month regardless of whether there is a transaction or not... how do I get a period (end of month) to appear every month for an account? My closing balance calculation also seems to be giving some incorrect results for some reason...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest](
    [Company] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LedgerAccount] [int] NULL,
    [FiscalPeriodType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountingDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AccountingDebitAmount] [numeric](32, 6) NOT NULL,
    [AccountingCreditAmount] [numeric](32, 6) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(34240.610000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(7.570000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(3.490000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(18740.040000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-05-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(23546.990000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(210643.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 248123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(3144.750000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(38.620000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(36646.380000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-05-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(15.330000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-07-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(791.160000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(625.880000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(22184.370000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-11-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(895.730000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(26.620000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(12.240000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-05-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(15.330000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-07-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(791.160000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(15374.610000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(54643.560000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 0, CAST(N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(421.210000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-04-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(457.660000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 0, CAST(N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(711715.490000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-04-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(16111.980000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(103438.450000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(8855.750000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(38.620000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(36646.380000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-05-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(15.330000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-07-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(791.160000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(625.890000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(625.900000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-11-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(895.730000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(26.620000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(12.240000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-04-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(10.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(22227.140000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(13563.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(32788.870000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(18283.750000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(457.660000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(3.540000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(9089.990000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-07-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(28277.890000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-11-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(17545.800000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(36912.220000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(307.580000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-04-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(10.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(7416.570000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(129.320000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(625.910000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-10-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(21272.100000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(350.650000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(12.240000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-03-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(3.400000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(25194.070000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(15374.610000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 0, CAST(N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(101385.640000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223423, 1, CAST(N'2017-10-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(80135.340000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(428.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223424, 1, CAST(N'2017-07-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.050000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(14951.440000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(12437.260000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 223425, 1, CAST(N'2017-10-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(120164.230000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(36912.220000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(307.580000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-04-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(10.780000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(7416.570000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(129.320000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(22184.370000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-10-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(21272.100000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(350.650000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 0, CAST(N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(464.760000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-02-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(9.760000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-06-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(25194.070000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TrialBalanceTest] ([Company], [LedgerAccount], [FiscalPeriodType], [AccountingDate], [AccountingDebitAmount], [AccountingCreditAmount]) VALUES (1234, 263123, 1, CAST(N'2017-08-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(129.320000 AS Numeric(32, 6)), CAST(0.000000 AS Numeric(32, 6)))
GO
```

Query

```
WITH Months
  AS (SELECT MONTH AS [Month]
        FROM (   VALUES (1),
                        (2),
                        (3),
                        (4),
                        (5),
                        (6),
                        (7),
                        (8),
                        (9),
                        (10),
                        (11),
                        (12)) x (MONTH) ),
     Base
  AS (SELECT      Company,
                  LedgerAccount,
                  M.[Month],
                  CASE
                       WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN EOMONTH(AccountingDate)
                       ELSE GA.AccountingDate END AS AccountingDate,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount - GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingOpeningBalance,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingDebitAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingCreditAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount - GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingNetChangeAmount
        FROM      Months AS M
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TrialBalanceTest AS GA
          ON MONTH(GA.AccountingDate) = M.[Month]
       GROUP BY CASE
                     WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN EOMONTH(AccountingDate)
                     ELSE GA.AccountingDate END,
                GA.Company,
                GA.LedgerAccount,
                M.Month),
     Base1
  AS (SELECT Base.Company,
             Base.LedgerAccount,
             Base.Month,
             Base.AccountingDate,
             SUM(Base.AccountingOpeningBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY Base.LedgerAccount) AS AccountingOpeningBalance,
             Base.AccountingDebitAmount,
             Base.AccountingCreditAmount,
             Base.AccountingNetChangeAmount,
             SUM(Base.AccountingOpeningBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY Base.LedgerAccount) + Base.AccountingNetChangeAmount AS AccountingClosingBalance
        FROM Base),
     Final
  AS (SELECT Base1.Company,
             Base1.LedgerAccount,
             Base1.Month,
             Base1.AccountingDate,
             LAG(Base1.AccountingClosingBalance, 1, Base1.AccountingOpeningBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY LedgerAccount ORDER BY Base1.Month) AS AccountingOpeningBalance,
             Base1.AccountingDebitAmount,
             Base1.AccountingCreditAmount,
             Base1.AccountingNetChangeAmount,
             Base1.AccountingClosingBalance
        FROM Base1)
SELECT *
  FROM Final
 ORDER BY LedgerAccount,
          AccountingDate;
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: I really suggest getting into the habit of using a single `INSERT INTO` with multiple rows defined in the `VALUES` table construct. Lot's of `INSERT` statements with single rows are *significantly* slower than one `INSERT` with many rows.

Comment: Yea i'm really struggling with stack overflows char limits, couldn't even get one full month in reposting with random percent data selection...

Comment: Well then using a single `INSERT` would greatly help with getting the character count down, @jhowe, as you'll use [about half](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ad0b05a3587ba56a4214df0bbb1fd01) the characters.

Comment: how do you use SSMS to do this? I use generate script table/data...

Comment: I took your existing statements, and did a little find and replace, and then just dumped whitespace at the start of the rows and added commas where needed. Took me [about 30 seconds in ADS](https://larnu.uk/i/Peek%202022-01-17%2015-51.gif). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it, combination of CTE, cumulative SUM and LAG (window functions) should be enough for anyone to resolve this type of query.

```
DECLARE @Company NVARCHAR(20) = N'2061'
DECLARE @Year INT = 2017;

WITH AccountingPeriods --Recursive CTE gets all periods for year
  AS (SELECT MIN(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 01, 31)) AS AccountingPeriod
        FROM GeneralAccountEntry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT EOMONTH(AccountingPeriod, 1) AS AccountingPeriod
        FROM AccountingPeriods
       WHERE AccountingPeriods.AccountingPeriod < DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 12, 31)),
     LedgerDimensionPeriod --Unique combinations of Ledger, Dimension, Period so that there are no empty periods for accounts
  AS (SELECT       DISTINCT GA.[Ledger],
                            GA.Company,
                            GA.PostingLayer,
                            GA.PostingLayerName,
                            AP.AccountingPeriod,
                            GA.LedgerDimension,
                            GA.AccountDisplayValue,
                            GA.TransactionCurrency,
                            GA.AccountingCurrency
        FROM       GeneralAccountEntry AS GA
       CROSS APPLY AccountingPeriods AS AP -- Apply every period to every account
       WHERE       GA.Company        = @Company
         AND       YEAR(GA.AccountingDate) = @Year
         AND       GA.FiscalPeriodType IN ( 0, 1 )),
     Base --Base calculations
  AS (SELECT      LDP.[Ledger],
                  LDP.Company,
                  LDP.PostingLayer,
                  LDP.PostingLayerName,
                  LDP.AccountingPeriod,
                  LDP.LedgerDimension,
                  LDP.AccountDisplayValue,
                  LDP.TransactionCurrency,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN
                               GA.TransactionCurrencyDebitAmount - GA.TransactionCurrencyCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS InitialTransactionOpeningBalance,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.TransactionCurrencyDebitAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS TransactionDebitAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.TransactionCurrencyCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS TransactionCreditAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN
                               GA.TransactionCurrencyDebitAmount - GA.TransactionCurrencyCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS TransactionNetChange,
                  LDP.AccountingCurrency,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount - GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS InitialAccountingOpeningBalance,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingDebitAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingCreditAmount,
                  SUM(CASE
                           WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 1 THEN GA.AccountingDebitAmount - GA.AccountingCreditAmount
                           ELSE 0 END) AS AccountingNetChange
        FROM      LedgerDimensionPeriod AS LDP
        LEFT JOIN GeneralAccountEntry AS GA
          ON LDP.[Ledger]         = GA.[Ledger]
         AND LDP.PostingLayer     = GA.PostingLayer
         AND LDP.LedgerDimension  = GA.LedgerDimension
         AND LDP.AccountingPeriod = CASE --Group Jan transactions into one date period
                                         WHEN GA.FiscalPeriodType = 0 THEN EOMONTH(GA.AccountingDate)
                                         ELSE GA.AccountingDate END
       GROUP BY LDP.[Ledger],
                LDP.Company,
                LDP.PostingLayer,
                LDP.PostingLayerName,
                LDP.AccountingPeriod,
                LDP.LedgerDimension,
                LDP.AccountDisplayValue,
                LDP.TransactionCurrency,
                LDP.AccountingCurrency),
     ClosingBalance
  AS (SELECT B.[Ledger],
             B.Company,
             B.PostingLayer,
             B.PostingLayerName,
             B.AccountingPeriod,
             B.LedgerDimension,
             B.AccountDisplayValue,
             B.TransactionCurrency,
             B.InitialTransactionOpeningBalance,
             B.TransactionDebitAmount,
             B.TransactionCreditAmount,
             B.TransactionNetChange,
             SUM(B.InitialTransactionOpeningBalance + B.TransactionNetChange) OVER (PARTITION BY [Ledger], 
                                                                                                 B.LedgerDimension 
                                                                                      ORDER BY B.AccountingPeriod) AS TransactionClosingBalance,
             B.AccountingCurrency,
             B.InitialAccountingOpeningBalance,
             B.AccountingDebitAmount,
             B.AccountingCreditAmount,
             B.AccountingNetChange,
             SUM(B.InitialAccountingOpeningBalance + B.AccountingNetChange) OVER (PARTITION BY B.[Ledger],
                                                                                               B.LedgerDimension
                                                                                      ORDER BY B.AccountingPeriod) AS AccountingClosingBalance
        FROM Base AS B),
     OpeningBalance
  AS (SELECT CB.[Ledger],
             CB.Company,
             CB.PostingLayer,
             CB.PostingLayerName,
             CB.AccountingPeriod,
             CB.LedgerDimension,
             CB.AccountDisplayValue,
             CB.TransactionCurrency,
             LAG(CB.TransactionClosingBalance, 1, CB.InitialTransactionOpeningBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY CB.[Ledger],
                                                                                                          CB.LedgerDimension
                                                                                                 ORDER BY CB.AccountingPeriod) AS TransactionOpeningBalance, --LAG retrieves previous records by partition
             CB.TransactionDebitAmount,
             CB.TransactionCreditAmount,
             CB.TransactionNetChange,
             CB.TransactionClosingBalance,
             CB.AccountingCurrency,
             LAG(CB.AccountingClosingBalance, 1, CB.InitialAccountingOpeningBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY CB.[Ledger],
                                                                                                        CB.LedgerDimension
                                                                                                 ORDER BY CB.AccountingPeriod) AS AccountingOpeningBalance, --LAG retrieves previous records by partition
             CB.AccountingDebitAmount,
             CB.AccountingCreditAmount,
             CB.AccountingNetChange,
             CB.AccountingClosingBalance
        FROM ClosingBalance AS CB),
     Final
  AS (SELECT *
        FROM OpeningBalance AS OB)
SELECT *
  FROM Final AS F;
```